# Initial size of svg background image in LeafletJs

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I wonder how to set initial zoom of the background image in LefletJs.

I have used this example

http://jsfiddle.net/rimig/86o3h89m/

```
// create the map
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [40.75, -74.2],
    zoom: 13
});

// create the image
var imageUrl = 'http://blackicemedia.com/presentations/2013-02-hires/img/awesome_tiger.svg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {
    className: 'tiger',
}).addTo(mymap);
```

I had tried to scale image with CSS

```
.tiger {
            width: 500px !important;
            display: none;
        }
```

but CSS is not applied to the image.

Where I do a mistake?

Comment: Zoom level is per-map, not per-layer. Please explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I can sound clearer, I want to predefine initial size of SVG image

Comment: That's what `imageBounds` is for. Note that you have a typo in your code between `bounds` and `imageBounds`, though.